# C# looping through an array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I am looping through an array of strings, such as (1/12/1992 apple truck 12/10/10 orange bicycle). The array's length will always be divisible by 3. I need to loop through the array and grab the first 3 items (I'm going to insert them into a DB) and then grab the next 3 and so on and so forth until all of them have been gone through.

```
//iterate the array
for (int i = 0; i < theData.Length; i++)
{
    //grab 3 items at a time and do db insert, continue until all items are gone. 'theData' will always be divisible by 3.
}
```

Comment: 5 answers submitted within 40 seconds of each other, all with the same (almost exact) information.  Haha.  Nice.

Comment: What I find interesting is that five answers were posted while I was writing mine... and *not a single one* got the upper boundary right.

Comment: As @Mahesh said:  You didn't ask a question.  Questions generally end with question marks (?).  You didn't describe what you've tried, what failed, and why you're having difficulty.

Comment: Is someone going trigger-happy with the downvotes...?

Comment: @Matt - on each iteration (when incrementing by 3), `theData[i]` should be your date, `theData[i+1]` should be your fruit type, and `theData[i+2]` should be your automobile. What's the problem?

Comment: What about a `foreach` for the initial array? Wondering why nobody has suggested that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just increment `i` by 3 in each step:

```
  Debug.Assert((theData.Length % 3) == 0);  // 'theData' will always be divisible by 3

  for (int i = 0; i < theData.Length; i += 3)
  {
       //grab 3 items at a time and do db insert, 
       // continue until all items are gone..
       string item1 = theData[i+0];
       string item2 = theData[i+1];
       string item3 = theData[i+2];
       // use the items
  }
```

To answer some comments, it is a given that  `theData.Length` is a multiple of 3 so there is no need to check for `theData.Length-2` as an upperbound. That would only mask errors in the preconditions.

Answer (score 10):

`i++` is the standard use of a loop, but not the only way. Try incrementing by 3 each time:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < theData.Length - 2; i+=3) 
    { 

        // use theData[i], theData[i+1], theData[i+2]

    }
```

Comment: You're the only one so far who won't get an out-of-bounds error on the last iteration; instead, you stop one iteration short. Try `i < theData.Length - 2`.

Comment: @mmyers - great minds think alike. :) Changed it already. But I don't think the check is necessary anyway, only put it in because it seemed logical...

Comment: The question states the length will be a multiple of 3, no need for the -2

Comment: @Henk: And right you are; if I'd downvoted you I'd take it back. Might want to draw attention to that point in your answer, though.

Comment: Any reason for the downvotes...? It seems that every answer to this post received a downvote.

Answer (score 4):

Not too difficult. Just increment the counter of the `for` loop by 3 each iteration and then offset the indexer to get the batch of 3 at a time:

```
for(int i=0; i < theData.Length; i+=3)
{
    var item1 = theData[i];
    var item2 = theData[i+1];
    var item3 = theData[i+2];
}
```

If the length of the array wasn't garuanteed to be a multiple of three, you would need to check the upper bound with `theData.Length - 2` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your for loop doesn't need to just add one.  You can loop by three.

```
for(int i = 0; i < theData.Length; i+=3)
{
  string value1 = theData[i];
  string value2 = theData[i+1];
  string value3 = theData[i+2];
}
```

Basically, you are just using indexes to grab the values in your array.  One point to note here, I am not checking to see if you go past the end of your array.  Make sure you are doing bounds checking!

Comment: Downvote?  What for?  (I noticed all answers except the first were downvoted.  Lame.)

Comment: the first was originally, but seems to have been taken off. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
//iterate the array
for (int i = 0; i < theData.Length; i+=3)
{
    //grab 3 items at a time and do db insert, continue until all items are gone. 'theData' will always be divisible by 3.
    var a = theData[i];
    var b = theData[i + 1];
    var c = theData[i + 2];
}
```

I've been downvoted for this answer once.  I'm pretty sure it is related to the use of theData.Length for the upperbound.  The code as is works fine because array is guaranteed to be a multiple of three as the question states.  If this guarantee wasn't in place, you would need to check the upper bound with theData.Length - 2 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more general solution:

```
int increment = 3;
for(int i = 0; i < theData.Length; i += increment)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < increment; j++)
   {
      if(i+j < theData.Length) {
         //theData[i + j] for the current index
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
string[] friends = new string[4];
friends[0]= "ali";
friends[1]= "Mike";
friends[2]= "jan";
friends[3]= "hamid";

for (int i = 0; i < friends.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(friends[i]);
}Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This question already contains multiple answers and an accepted answer. Can you explain (by editing your answer) where your answer differs from the other answers? Also know that Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.